# Make Javascript Load Before Content

Tags: javascript

I have this site set up so that if you visit from Switzerland (CH), two of the links at the top disappear.

However, they're disappearing too slowly and you can see the script happen.

I was wondering if there is a way to make the script run and have the links disappear before anyone can see?

Here is the script:

```
<script>
const url = (() => {
    const protocol = "https";
    const domain = "freeipapi.com";
    const endpoint = "api/json/";
    return `${protocol}://${domain}/${endpoint}`;
})();

const fetchLocationData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const data = await response.json();

        const countryCode = data.countryCode;

        // Introduce complex DOM manipulation
        const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-hide-by-country="${countryCode}"]`)];
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            const element = elements[i];
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // Simulate delay
            element.style.display = "none";
        }

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
        return null;
    }
}

(async () => {
    await fetchLocationData();
})();

</script>
```

Comment: Why not just hide them with css in the first place?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't explain. The content should be available to users from all other countries. However, some things need to be hidden from users from CH.

Answer (score 3):

Invert the logic.  Instead of conditionally *hiding* the content, hide it by default and then conditionally *show* it.

So instead of this:

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

Style the element(s) with CSS to already use `display: none;` and then do this:

```
element.style.display = "block"; // or inline, or whatever value it should be
```

You'd just need to invert the `querySelectorAll` selector as well, so it selects elements which *don't* match the country code.

For example:

```js
const url = (() => {
    const protocol = "https";
    const domain = "freeipapi.com";
    const endpoint = "api/json/";
    return `${protocol}://${domain}/${endpoint}`;
})();

const fetchLocationData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const data = await response.json();

        const countryCode = data.countryCode;

        // Select all elements to show
        const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-hide-by-country]:not([data-hide-by-country="${countryCode}"])`)];
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            const element = elements[i];
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

            // show the element
            element.style.display = "block";
        }

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
        return null;
    }
}

(async () => {
    await fetchLocationData();
})();
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-hide-by-country="US">Hide for US.</div>
<div data-hide-by-country="CA">Hide for CA.</div>
```

The difference here is that all potentially-hidden elements are initially hidden by CSS, and then the JavaScript code iterates over the non-matching elements and shows those ones.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - That was very easy to plug in and working well.

However, now for users in other countries, the hidden elements are loading with a little bit of delay.

This is much better than how it was previous, but I wonder if there is a way to hide the javascript load delay.

Comment: @Dnilly99: The delay exists either way.  Content is either shown by default and then later hidden, or it's hidden by default and then later shown.  If you have some other way of determining what content to show in server-side code before returning the page to the user, that could allow for an initial page state which meets the need.  But if the only way to know the information you need about the user is to make an AJAX request then that's always going to involve *some* delay.  You could potentially improve the UX with loading indicators, skeleton elements, etc.